# "jar_project" Builder in Eclipse CN1 project loops on refresh

Tags: codenameone

CN1 projects have an additional Builder "jar_project" configured.

Apparently this builder is looping when "Refresh using native hooks or polling" is checked in Eclipse Preferences -> General -> Workspace. "Refresh using native hooks or polling" is a nice feature to refresh the workspace files for changes made outside the IDE.

When editing the builder configuration via right click on a project -> properties -> builders -> jar_project and chiising edit I see that in the refresh tab the option "The project containing the selected resource" is selected. That is probably incorrect.

Anyway what is the builders "jar_project" purpose? Does it really need to be called after change of any project file?

Answer (score 1):

The project is built using the `build.xml` file. It verifies that compilation works.

We don't support that eclipse mode and don't test against it. If you want to make changes manually they might work but we can't warrant them.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to remove this useless builder. Apparently it's better to work without this "jar_project" builder. I don't see any use for it.